# Problem with slider images loading time and display

Tags: css, slider, loading, display

I have a problem with the sliders on my website (I just started coding recently).

http://www.willybass.com

Depending on the browser and the connexion, the images sometime do not load and the slider displays completely flat (then it only display correctly if you hit refresh, or sometimes it loads and displays, again depending on the browsers and connexion).

Does anyone know what is the best solution to this issue ? (to at least display a grey background with the dimension of picture that didnt load, while it loads)

Comment: height of slider-track is 1px, try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771891/slick-images-become-1px-height

Comment: The issue is that my pictures within the sliders are all the same height and width. So if i were to do that some of the pictures would be stretched